# Exchange EWS Managed API - Undelivarable mail notification does not have the DateTimeReceived property

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

When finding items from a `Exchange 2010 Server journaling inbox`, there are some notifications on undelivered mails.

When processing these emails and trying to read the `DateTimeReceived` property, I get an `ServiceObjectPropertyException` with the error:

```
You must load or assign this property before you can read its value.
```

Is there a way of identifying such emails, or loading the `DateTimeReceived` property (even it will be null)?

My Code is something like this:

```
FindItemsResults<Item> mails = folder.FindItems(searchConditions, countConstraint);
foreach (Item item in mails)
{
  EmailMessage email = (EmailMessage)item;
  email.Load();
  DateTime receivedTime = email.DateTimeReceived;
  ....
}
```

Those emails are from a journaling mailbox that has a copy of monitored mailbox every email sent to it.

The specific emails that do not have this property, are notifications about emails sent from one of those mailboxes, but could not be delivered.

Through MFCMapi I was able to view the message, and the `PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME` property is set.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `DateTimeReceived` is considered a first class property so you need to load your email with specific properties.

```
email.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived));
```

Answer (score 0):

try `((MailItem)item).DateTimeReceived` - for reference see

- http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-allitems-search-folder-from.html
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/8c71ace4-43d2-4ba2-88f2-16376dad828f
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.transport.mailitem.datetimereceived%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx